# How to update listview after inserting a record to database?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sql-update

I have a problem with updating the listview after inserting a record to the database.

OnCreate, I load data from the database to the listview like that:

```
Cursor c = db.getAllCategory();
    List<String> l = db.getItemByFilteredCategory();

    //add total goals that match with each category
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int totalGoals = db.getMyGoalByCat(c.getInt(0)).getCount();
            db.updateCategory(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), totalGoals);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    //update category list
    c = db.getAllCategory();

    //add items to list
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.custom_categorylist,
            c,
            new String[]{"_id", "categoryName", "categoryDescription", "totalGoals"},
            new int[]{R.id.customViewCatId, R.id.customViewCategory, R.id.customViewCatDescription, R.id.customViewTargetNumber});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

On the same activity, I have a button. When the button is clicked, I show a Dialog including 2 buttons: Create and Cancel.

If the Create button is clicked, I insert the new data to the database and dismiss the dialog.

```
btnAddCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_create_category);
            dialog.setTitle("Create new category");
            dialog.show();

            Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCategory);
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            final EditText etCatName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etCatName);
            final EditText etCatDescription = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etCatDescription);

            Button btnCreate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateCategory);
            btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DBAdapter dbSub = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                    dbSub.openDB();
                    dbSub.insertCategory(etCatName.getText().toString(),etCatDescription.getText().toString(), 0);
                    dbSub.closeDB();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

At that moment, I will be back on the main Activity with the listview. How can I get the listview update at this step?

Cheers,

Comment: try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after inserting into database

Comment: notifydataset works when the underlying array or equivalent class object reference used to fill up the list is modified. Just by calling notify will not help.

Comment: Do I need to declare the adapter object?

Answer (score 1):

To update the data in the list you have to call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**.

Comment: I am not really understand. What is the adapter?

Comment: lv.setAdapter(adapter);

This adapter within the brackets . Check your code.

Comment: yes but I could not find the method notifyDataSetChanged? Is it because I declare the adapter inside onCreate method and then call it inside the Dialog?

Comment: Yes, Declare adapter globally and call it.

Comment: Humm, seems like it doesn't work mate. I my adapter is like adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.custom_categorylist,
                c,
                new String[]{"_id", "categoryName", "categoryDescription", "totalGoals"},
                new int[]{R.id.customViewCatId, R.id.customViewCategory, R.id.customViewCatDescription, R.id.customViewTargetNumber});

Comment: Method is already there. Type adapter. then look for Hint. This method will be enlisted in the Hint.

Comment: yes I did exactly the same but there is no notifyDataSetChanged here. Must be something wrong with my adapter object.

Comment: @MaiLongDao check this [Viedo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNoeFkXCZ6w) 
You will get and idea about it. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Cool, I will take a look and let you know mate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For this still wondering why they can't find the notifyDataSetChanged method, you need to cast the adapter to your customAdapter. e.g. `( (MyListAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

If the onClickListener is within onCreate

```
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DBAdapter dbSub = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                    dbSub.openDB();
                    dbSub.insertCategory(etCatName.getText().toString(),etCatDescription.getText().toString(), 0);
                    dbSub.closeDB();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Unless

```
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DBAdapter dbSub = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                        dbSub.openDB();
                        dbSub.insertCategory(etCatName.getText().toString(),etCatDescription.getText().toString(), 0);
                        dbSub.closeDB();
    lv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Hope this can help.